# Peak hour in tex.SE

Tags: discussion

I am slowly becoming a frequent user in this site.

So, in this site, I am wondering is there analytics to see which is (are) the peak hour(s) (on an average).

Also, if possible, are there any ways for me to see those stats?

Comment: Does https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7767/35864 help?

Comment: @moewe got it, thanks!

Comment: And [https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6840/is-it-better-to-ask-in-the-high-traffic-time](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6840/is-it-better-to-ask-in-the-high-traffic-time), which I was not aware of when I asked my question.

Comment: @marmot undid my edits.

Comment: @marmot I know dat legacy, I remember once a discussion I had. But nevertheless, I undid the edits by doing another edit (which renders the original version). Side info: I'm on the side of no `mathjax` here :D

Comment: @marmot you are welcome and great to know!

Comment: Peak hour is when a TikZ question asked. Then all nomads come out of their caves.

Comment: @percusse I think this should have been the answer for all the previous questions as well (jk). I thought it was hunting ;)